# How to plot a line from day Open to day Close using plot in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9ycT.png)In this image I have made what I was looking for using line.new method. But, as the line.new have limits for number of lines it is not showing for all the historical periods and not working for more than 4hr time frame.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. Will show on all candles but you need to manually place the indicator on top of the candles using the script's "More" menu (the 3 dots next to its name on the chart) and "Visual order/Bring to front". You can control the color of the line, but not its thickness.

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
plotcandle(open, open, close, open, wickcolor = color.black, bordercolor = na)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for replying. I should have made my requirement clear. I have attached the screenshot of my indicator. It was created using line.new. Is it possible get the same result using plot.

Comment: You can use a technique like this one, but it's pretty complex, not very robust, and lines will appear late: https://www.tradingview.com/script/4JgxpBWY-Automatic-Trendlines-Proof-of-Concept/

Comment: Yes it is complex.